# update bundled taglib standard version inside jstl 1.2

Tags: java, maven, jsp, jstl

In my project I am using

```
  <dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
    <version>1.2</version>
    <type>jar</type>
  </dependency>
```

but after our security team evaluated the jars it found out that the bundled org.apache.taglibs:standard jar is version 1.2.1 which has a security vulnerability (https://web.nvd.nist.gov/view/vuln/detail?vulnId=CVE-2015-0254). Apache has already fixed it in version 1.2.3 (https://tomcat.apache.org/taglibs/standard/).

In addition, `META-INF/c.tld` shows that it is actually JSTL version 1.1 instead of 1.2 (see [JSTL version 1.2 declared but 1.1 delivered from Maven Repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6535119/jstl-version-1-2-declared-but-1-1-delivered-from-maven-repository)). Maybe this error is connected to the wrong taglibs standard version?

Nevertheless, what should I do to update the bundled taglibs standard version inside jstl?

Comment: As to vulrenability, is this webapp really using JSTL XML tags? (e.g. <x:parse> or <x:transform>). Their use was strongly discouraged since JSP 2.0 more than a decade ago (along with JSTL SQL tags) and you should be using "plain" JAXP or JAXB instead. As long as your webapp doesn't anywhere use the discouraged JSTL <x:...> (nor <sql:...>) tags, it should be safe.

Comment: you should remove jars that are vulnerable, clean your local repo, fix errors in `pom.xml`, clean temp folders or recreate a project from scratch, rebuild, repackage. If you done all this steps then it should update libraries, otherwise you should ask someone who can help.

Comment: @BalusC tbh, no idea if it is used. "my project" is meant as a enterprise-level app where my only task is to fix security vulnerabilities.
RomanC i dont think this helps because this is the latest official jar from the central maven repo. it just did not get updated with the newest jars it bundles.

Answer (score 10):

Instead of the whole `jstl-1.2.jar` download the three latest versions of the needed components:

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.taglibs/taglibs-standard-spec -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.taglibs</groupId>
    <artifactId>taglibs-standard-spec</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.5</version>
</dependency>

<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.taglibs/taglibs-standard-impl -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.taglibs</groupId>
    <artifactId>taglibs-standard-impl</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.5</version>
</dependency>

<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.taglibs/taglibs-standard-jstlel -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.taglibs</groupId>
    <artifactId>taglibs-standard-jstlel</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.5</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Will this work with all servlet containers? Or it has compatibility issues with and not with other? I am planning to use it with jboss and WAS servers.